# Doxygen missed entries (depending on order)

Tags: doxygen

Want to generate html-documenation from a documented c-header. But I have a strange problem with doxygen:
Some entries (enums, structs, ..) are missed in the html. If I reorder one of the missed entries (put them among two others that are already displayed, than it will shown too ?!?
Is there a rule for the order of entries? If so, can I disable this rule?

Use 1.8.11 in Linux and latest (1.8.14) in Windows. 
As for example I have a few structs a,b,c,d , and struct d struct is part of c.
In "C" I need to write d before c, otherwise I get  compiler error. But doxygen - for some strange reason lists c only if it is located before d. So either I can compile or have a complete documentation.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? The description is quite cryptic, please give a small example.

Comment: Please make a small code example not just a description. Also specify whether or not you use a default Doxyfile or if there are any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small example and with this example I do see all elements:

```
/** \file */

/** docu structure a */
struct a
{
  /** docu member a */
  int mem_a;
};

/** docu structure b */
struct b
{
  /** docu member b */
  int mem_b;
};

/** docu structure d */
struct d
{
  /** docu member d */
  int mem_d;
};

/** docu structure c */
struct c
{
  /** docu member c */
  int mem_c;
  /** docu structure inside c */
  struct d str_d;
};
```

I have used a default Doxyfile (doxygen -g).

Answer (score 0):

The header file was quite large - to large to post it here - so I tried to reduce it and found the issue. The struct that will not displayed has a @code blabla statement in its doxygen header but it needs an @endcode (that was missed). Sorry for this false alarm. Thanks to albert, for this help. Asking the right questions helps too!